# Multiple if/for statements to set conditions of specific email and pull an attachment

Tags: python

I have written below with the intention to scan the inbox (in reverse so it picks up the latest file), for an email that is received today and has the subject "Interest":

```
for message in reversed(messages):
    if message.SentOn.date() == today and 'Interest' in str(message.subject):
        print("Found message")
        attachments = message.Attachments
        attachment = attachments.Item(1)
        for attachment in message.Attachments:
            attachment.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(path, str(attachment)))
    else:
        print("No interest to be booked")
```

This works however i want to also caveat the fact that sometime the email can be sent with subject "interest", i.e. lowercase "i". I tried changing the first line of the code to:

```
if message.SentOn.date() == today and ['Interest' in str(message.subject) or 'interest' in str(message.subject)]:
```

But then for some reason this doesn't work. What confuses me is it still finds the message, but it just can't pull the attachment. This is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:/Excel/python/todaysdateandformat.py", line 20, in <module>
    attachment = attachments.Item(1)
  File "<COMObject <unknown>>", line 2, in Item
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'Array index out of bounds.', None, 0, -2147352567), None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternatively to replacing the square brackets with the round ones, a simpler and more flexible way could be lower-casing the subject before matching it:

```
if message.SentOn.date() == today and 'interest' in str(message.subject).lower():
  ...
```

Comment: Ha, we were mere seconds apart.

Comment: Thank you, all of these solutions worked :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if message.SentOn.date() == today and ['Interest' in str(message.subject) or 'interest' in str(message.subject)]:
```

The brackets return a list, not a boolean.

You should write :

```
if message.SentOn.date() == today and ('Interest' in str(message.subject) or 'interest' in str(message.subject)):
```

Comment: Thank you, all of these solutions worked :)

Answer (score 0):

Just replace [] with () in if statement. Now it creates a list [True] or [False]. Both of them evaluates to True.

Comment: Thank you, all of these solutions worked :)

Answer (score 0):

> This works however i want to also caveat the fact that sometime the
> email can be sent with subject "interest", i.e. lowercase "i".

Convert the string to lowercase and then only check for "interest".

`if message.SentOn.date() == today and 'interest' in str(message.subject).lower():`

If you have other conditions to check for, you can indeed use a generator or a list comprehension and combine it with the `any` builtin (or `all`, if required). Something like this:

`if message.SentOn.date() == today and any(s in str(message.subject) for s in search_terms)`

Comment: Thank you, all of these solutions worked :)